# Style Drupal's Print Module PDF

Tags: css, pdf, drupal-7, tcpdf, print-module

How would one do this in Drupal 7? I want to add a few small style edits to the way the PDF outputs. I am using TCPDF. I read somewhere that its not posible with TCPDF, but other sources say it is. Should I be switching to dompdf? I've read the documentation but just can't seem to understand which file generates the PDF.

I have the module successfully generating a PDF from a View, so this is the last step in moving on with this project.

Answer (score 0):

For anytime you want to style PDFs use `DOMPDF`, it will be less painful. Then style your pdf using `print.css` in the sites/domain.com/themes/yourtheme/css folder.

You can also copy the `print.tpl.php` file from the module's folder and paste it in sites/domain.com/themes/yourtheme/templates to choose exactly what you want to display in your pdf.

Comment: I got something working with wkhtmltopdf which I believe will let me adjust the template layout and CSS... although I haven't tried to adjust them yet. I will need to soon though. Do you think `DOMPDF` is a better solution? I'm totally willing to use whatever is the most effective and clean solution.

Comment: With wkhtmltopdf it is very WYSISYG brought to you by Google. So it will print exactly what you have on the screen with print/. Google Chrome uses this to print its pages. I have never used it though so I cannot speak for it.But DOMPDF is just as good and very configurable. Its all upto you and how much you want to experiment/learn.